# How to extract an ID from JSON response and use it as path variable in another HTTP requests in JMeter

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jsonpath

I have a requirement where I will run a search API which will return me a list of object, each with unique 'facilityID'. I need to create  a list of them and use them in another HTTP Delete Request. I have to pass the values as path variable and there are multiple simultaneous threads.

Example:
Search API return following IDs: [18c2, 77v3, 45f1]

Now in my Delete HTTP Request, different threads should fetch an Id from the list and bind it to the path variable of the URL.

I read about JSON extractor and am using following expression in Search API,

```
$.result[*].facilityId
```

This should return me the list, but how do I make sure that each thread should pick one value from it and hit the API?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you came up with the correct JSON Extractor configuration and got the following JMeter Variables, i.e. you can observe the next values for the [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) in the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

```
facilityId_1=18c2
facilityId_2=77v3
facilityId_3=45f1
facilityId_matchNr=3
```

[image]

If your goal is to run Delete requests concurrently for each thread - you can consider using [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions combination - this way each JMeter thread will delete its own `facilityId`

[image]

Check out [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) for more information if needed.